# sonarqube docker java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am using sonarqube using docker. I lunch sonarqube image using following command

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube \
    -p 9000:9000 \
    -v /home/ubuntu/sonarqubeconf/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf \
    -v /home/ubuntu/sonarqubeconf/data:/opt/sonarqube/data \
    -v /home/ubuntu/sonarqubeconf/logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs \
    -v /home/ubuntu/sonarqubeconf/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions \
    -e -Dsonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx15048m \
    -e -Dsonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx15048m \
    -e SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx15048m \
    sonarqube
```

And Using sonar scanner using Jenkins. When I run sonar scanner it's run but getting an error in background task

Here is my analysis property

```
sonar.projectKey=vrs-es-frontend
sonar.projectName=VRS front end
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.ws.timeout=3600
```

ERROR

> Error Details: vrs-es-frontend [Project Analysis]
>   Error Details
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I search lots on the internet but not get any perfect solution.

Comment: Do you get this error also if analysing a small example project?

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this for only for large projects. Small projects working fine

Comment: So the problem is not very SonarQube related. Have a look [here](https://royvanrijn.com/blog/2018/05/java-and-docker-memory-limits/).

Comment: Do you know where is the issue exactly?

Comment: In the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/monitoring/) of SonarQube you can also find some suggestions. Based on this information you have to investigate further and update your question if needed.